# How to pass binary data and meta-data using HTTP GET

Tags: networking, http, protocol, network-protocols

I'm using BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler in order to implement my server.

currently I repsonse to get request with merely binary data file.

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-Type", 'application/octet-stream')
self.send_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(FILEPATH)))
fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
self.send_header("Content-Length", str(fs.st_size))
self.end_headers()
```

Now it's requested to add another section which include some short json formatted configuration data (i.e. `{'status': 'ok', 'type': 'keepalive'}`) and i'd rather pass this information on the same response separated by unique http header or by the http body.

What is the best way to do so ? I'd like to know in general, whether it's possible to add additional header to the current get response, or to split this into separated GET requests: one for the meta-data and another for the binary data.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, please consider the [topics that are relevant](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to this exchange - I think your question is better suited for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)